# problem with using mysql with nodejs server with transaction query

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, client-server, pug

So essentially I am using a transaction in my nodejs server with mysql to pull the first row and then delete that row from the table.
the code for this looks like:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  connection.query("START TRANSACTION; SELECT * FROM data.train_data LIMIT 1; DELETE FROM data.train_data LIMIT 1; COMMIT;",(err,rows) => {
    if(err){
      console.log('Error selecting tweets from Database...');
      return;
    }
    console.log('Successfully recieved tweets from database');
     res.render('index', {
       title: 'Tweet Labeler',
       data: rows[1]
     });
  });
```

The problem is that even though the query is working correctly, when I reroute to the page in my client side javascript like this:

```
             function relClick(){
               var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
               var newData = {'tweet':data[0].tweet,'relevant':1};
               var jsonData = JSON.stringify(newData);
               xhr.open("POST","/",true);
               xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json');
               xhr.send(jsonData);
               console.log("Clicked Relevant");
               xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
               xhr.open("GET","/",true);
               xhr.send();
               nextItem();
             }
```

I essentially want to repeat this process and grab the new top row from the table but by using print statements I have deduced that it is somehow not realizing that the row has been deleted even though when I use mysql workbench I can see the row has been deleted.
As you can see with this screenshot it continues to grab the row with the id 24 even though it has been deleted?
[image]

I am really confused on why this is. Hopefully someone with more experience can assist me because I am very new to this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` clause, it's indeterminate which row will be returned by the SELECT. (A relation is unordered ie. there is no first tuple). With the DELETE statement, its indeterminate which row will be deleted. There is no guarantee that the DELETE will operate on the row returned by the preceding SELECT. (It might, but there isn't a guarantee it will.) If  two or more sessions perform the set of statements concurrently, the SELECT statement in multiple sessions could return the same row. Also, the SELECT statement doesn't obtain a lock, like `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` would.

Comment: It seems this is attempting to use MySQL table as a queue. "5 SUBTLE WAYS YOU'RE USING MYSQL AS A QUEUE, AND WHY IT'LL BITE YOU" https://www.engineyard.com/blog/5-subtle-ways-youre-using-mysql-as-a-queue-and-why-itll-bite-you ... https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/09/15/percona-case-study-estante-virtual/

Comment: So if I just change my delete and select to first order the entries by like their ID's in ascending order or something then perform these, then you think it will work?

Comment: I changed both of them to first order them by asc based on the train_id and they still don't work, is there anything I need to do with like refreshing my connection with the database or something to make sure its seeing the updated rows  or something?